# request.post method in a Promise jump out

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

guys:

Recently I come up with a problem, let's see my code first:

```
var foo = function () {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        request.post(
            someAddress,
            { form: someData },

            function (error, res, body) {

                responseHandler(error, res, body, resolve, reject);
            });
    });

    return promise;
};

function responseHandler(error, res, body,resolve,reject) {
    if (error || res.statusCode != 200) {
        try {
            if (res) {
                error = error || { error: res.statusMessage };
                error.statusCode = res.statusCode || 204;
                reject(error);
            }
            else {
                reject({
                    statusCode: 204,
                    message: 'Unspecified Error'
                });
            }
        }
        catch (ex) {
            reject(ex);
        }
    }
    else {
        try {
            resolve(body ? JSON.parse(body) : '')
        }
        catch (ex) {
            reject(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my code. When it runs to the `request.post` , it'll jump out of foo.

- Is the problem caused by my bad coding or is there something I was missing?
- I want it to stay and wait for the respond so that i can run though `foo()` , What should I do?

---

Actually, the whole code would be:

```
function bar() {
 var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  foo().then(doSth and resolve);
 })
  return promise;
 }
```

And then I used `bar` somewhere with another promise like:

```
   function chain() {
     somePromise()
      .then(bar)
      .then(anotherPromise)
      .then(...);
   }
```

In the end it goes with

```
 promiseA
  .then(chain)
  .then(promiseB)
  .then(promiseC)
```

When my code runs in `bar()` and dive into `foo()`, it posts something and jumps out of `chain()` and directly goes through `promiseB` and `promiseC`.

The code would go back to `responseHandler()` only when the respond is received.

I've tried a `setTimeout()` like

```
 promiseA
  .then(function(){
     setTimeout(
       chain(),
       400
     );
   })
  .then(promiseB)
  .then(promiseC)
```

It did works but the code stops after `chain()` and never meet `promiseB` and `promiseC`.

Comment: What errors are you receiving?

Comment: It isn't an error, just that it doesn't go the way I think It should be.@Bwaxxlo

Comment: `chain` needs to _return_ a promise as well (`return somePromise()...`).

Comment: @Cyper that's because `setTimeout` as a function doesn't return anything to the promise. So, `promiseB` just gets undefined from `promiseA`.

Comment: @Bwaxxlo I see... that's why `setTimeout` didn't work! Thanks!

Comment: the last `then(...)` in `chain` returns a promise, would it return by `chain`? @robertklep

Comment: Yeah, but `chain` is inside `setTimeout`. So, anything inside `setTimeout`, will be locked from the outside. The only way you can resolve a `Promise` inside a `setTimeout` is by wrapping the `setTimeout` inside another Promise and return that promise (see explained code: http://pastebin.com/raw/2jjascuD)

Answer (score 0):

`foo()` will (immediately) return a promise, which represents a future response value.

If you want to wait for the value to become available, you need to wait for it by using `.then()`:

```
foo().then(body => { ... });
```

Comment: I used `.then()` in after `foo()` in another function and It seems not working.